# Changing Image based on Cursor location on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create this effect - called Rotating Heads. It is Basically using the cursor location on the Display to change the Image. So my idea is the person that I have photos of to follow the cursor like on [this example](https://www.cloudtec.ch/blog/web/2014/change-image-with-jquery-mouse-position). The problem is that when I use this code there is something wrong and It is not working. Probably some stuff is outdated.

```js
/* Declaring the global variables */
            var mouseX;
            var mouseY;
            var imageOne;
            var imageTwo;
            var imageThree;
            var imageFour;
            var imageFive;
            
            /* Calling the initialization function */
            jQuery(init);
            
            /* The images need to re-initialize on load and on resize, or else the areas
             * where each image is displayed will be wrong. */
            jQuery(window).on("load", init);
            jQuery(window).resize(init);
            
            /* Setting the mousemove event caller */
            jQuery(window).mousemove(getMousePosition);
            
            /* This function is called on document ready, on load and on resize
             * and initiallizes all the images */
            function init(){
                
                /* Instanciate the mouse position variables */
                mouseX = 0;
                mouseY = 0;
                
                /* Instanciate a HeadImage class for every image */
                imageOne = new HeadImage("one");
                imageTwo = new HeadImage("two");
                imageThree = new HeadImage("three");
                imageFour = new HeadImage("four");
                imageFive = new HeadImage("five");
            }
            
            /* This function is called on mouse move and gets the mouse position. 
             * It also calls the HeadImage function to display the correct image*/
            function getMousePosition(event){
                
                /* Setting the mouse position variables */
                mouseX = event.pageX;
                mouseY = event.pageY;
                
                /*Calling the setImageDirection function of the HeadImage class
                 * to display the correct image*/
                imageOne.setImageDirection();
                imageTwo.setImageDirection();
                imageThree.setImageDirection();
                imageFour.setImageDirection();
                imageFive.setImageDirection();
            }
            
  
var className;
var imageTop;
var imageLeft;
var imageBottom;
var imageRight;

function HeadImage(className){
    
    /* Setting the global instance of classname to the given parameter*/
    this.className = className;
    
    /* Calculating the borders of the image */
    this.imageLeft = jQuery("."+this.className+">.head-image").offset().left;
    this.imageRight = this.imageLeft + jQuery("."+this.className+">.head-image").width();
    this.imageTop = jQuery("."+this.className+">.head-image").offset().top;
    this.imageBottom = this.imageTop + jQuery("."+this.className+">.head-image").height();
    
    /* This function determines where the mouse pointer is relative to the image
     * and displays the correct image accordingly. */
    this.setImageDirection = function(){
        jQuery("."+this.className+">.head-image").css("z-index","0");
        if(mouseX >= this.imageLeft && mouseX <= this.imageRight && mouseY <= this.imageTop){
            jQuery("."+this.className+">.up").css("z-index","1");
        } else if(mouseX < this.imageLeft && mouseY < this.imageTop){
            jQuery("."+this.className+">.up-left").css("z-index","1");
        } else if(mouseX <= this.imageLeft && mouseY >= this.imageTop && mouseY <= this.imageBottom){
            jQuery("."+this.className+">.left").css("z-index","1");
        } else if(mouseX < this.imageLeft && mouseY > this.imageBottom){
            jQuery("."+this.className+">.down-left").css("z-index","1");
        } else if(mouseX >= this.imageLeft && mouseX <= this.imageRight && mouseY >= this.imageBottom){
            jQuery("."+this.className+">.down").css("z-index","1");
        } else if(mouseX > this.imageRight && mouseY > this.imageBottom){
            jQuery("."+this.className+">.down-right").css("z-index","1");
        } else if(mouseX >= this.imageRight && mouseY >= this.imageTop && mouseY <= this.imageBottom){
            jQuery("."+this.className+">.right").css("z-index","1");
        } else if(mouseX > this.imageRight && mouseY < this.imageTop){
            jQuery("."+this.className+">.up-right").css("z-index","1");
        } else{
            jQuery("."+this.className+">.front").css("z-index","1");
            jQuery(".text-holder").css("display","none");
            jQuery("."+this.className+".text-holder").css("display","block");
        }
    };
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(176,176,176) !important;
}

.opala {
    position: fixed;
    height:100vh;
   width:100%;
   top:0px;
}

.image-holder{
    position: relative;      
    left:0px;
    height:100vh;
 width:100%;
}

.head-image{
    position: absolute;
    width:46%;
    margin-left:27%;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index: 0;
 height:;
}


.front{
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-holder one">          
       <img class="head-image up" src="http://test.valerikarageorgiev.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/front.jpg"/>
       <img class="head-image up-left" src="http://test.valerikarageorgiev.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/left.jpg"/>
       <img class="head-image left" src="http://test.valerikarageorgiev.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/left.jpg"/>
       <img class="head-image down-left" src="http://test.valerikarageorgiev.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/left.jpg"/>
       <img class="head-image down" src="http://test.valerikarageorgiev.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/front.jpg"/>
       <img class="head-image down-right" src="http://test.valerikarageorgiev.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/upright.jpg"/>
       <img class="head-image right" src="http://test.valerikarageorgiev.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/upright.jpg"/>
       <img class="head-image up-right" src="http://test.valerikarageorgiev.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/upright.jpg"/>
       <img class="head-image front" src="http://test.valerikarageorgiev.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/front.jpg"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you importing jquery?

Comment: I am using this Code, that was on my website where I was loading jQuery and it was working. But when I put it on WordPress(jQuery is loaded by default) it causes Issues some functions stopped to work, and sometimes even the Heads are not working. I am seeing the rotating heads are not working here too.

Comment: @ВалериК. after adding jquery to your snippet it's kinda working.

Comment: Yeah it is working when you add it to the snippet, but stop to work completely when added to WordPress. Probably because it is loaded Twice?

Comment: @ВалериК.Maybe jquery is being loaded after this script. Check your console for errors and let us know what you find

Comment: The strange thing is I uploaded it to two different accounts. in the first one is loading, and it is working but makes some anomalies, like some animations stopped to work. On the other account witch is mine it is Not Working it the Console says "jQuery is not defined"